# Using jQuery fadeIn Effect Plugin on :hover for links

Tags: jquery

I am creating links in which their background change on mouse hover it's easy to make this with CSS but I want a fade-out effect for the original background showing the hover one slowly. I want to use a jQuery Plugin to make this fade (in/out) effect apply to links having certain classes.

All I want is that to make the `.CLASS:hover` fade in when hovering or `.CLASS` to fade out showing `.CLASS:hover` slowly... without changing to different classes in which one for the original background and the other for the hovering one.

Comment: You don't need jquery for this; use CSS transitions: .MyClass{ transition: background 0.5 ease;}

Comment: It won't work for IE -10

Comment: answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004905/jquery-hovers-dont-work-in-ie10-but-works-in-lower-ie-versions

Comment: @user2217482: IE10 supports CSS transitions just fine; not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with **`CSS3-Transitions`**. Support is great (all modern browsers, even IE)

```
#foo {background:red; @include transition(background 1s)}
#foo:hover {background:yellow}
```

Pure CSS:

```
#foo {
background:red;
-webkit-transition:background 1s;
-moz-transition:background 1s;
-o-transition:background 1s;
transition:background 1s
}

#foo:hover {background:yellow}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css3

```
.CLASS{
    background: <put the color here>;
    transition: background 0.5 ease;
}
.CLASS:hover{
    background: <put the other color here>;
}
```